For integer programming, CPU vs RAM vs GPU, which is more critical for faster computing times overall
For integer programming application where usage is made of CPLEX or Gurobi or other state of the art solver, is it better to go with a faster CPU or is it better to go for higher RAM (memory) or does it make sense to use a GPU (NVIDIA, etc.)?
I am evaluating options of a single CPU with more cores vs CPU with fewer cores but then procuring a GPU in its place?
I have done some preliminary study and it appears that with OpenMP, it is possible to not only "easily" parallelize on a single CPU with multiple cores but also offload to a GPU. All of the examples I have seen are for canonical matrix operations/applications in image processing. I am curious to know if any benchmarks are available for integer programming?
Specifically, my questions are:
(a) Are solvers automatically capable of taking advantage of all available hardware on their own? i.e., if a GPU is available, with just default options from the user, can solvers offload work to GPUs on their own without any specific setting from the user? [in this case, user code is minimal]
(b) If multiple separation routines (for different classes of inequalities, say) need to be run given the current fractional LP solution, (in a branch and cut application), does it make sense to parallelize these separation routines via multiple threads or is it better to offload on a GPU?  [in this case, the user needs to do more coding/parallelization via OpenMP, etc. and write their own separation routines, and calls to the LP solver are alone given to the CPLEX or other solvers]

Some related questions that may be interesting. (1), (2), (3).

Your prelim study does not transfer to math-opt at all (opposed to image-processing or even neural-networks; the keyword is sparsity, although there are other reasons too)! Currently no general-purpose MILP solver will even run a single cycle on any GPU. Maybe start with Gurobi Webinar/YT to get some introduction and multicore benchmark numbers (of a single vendor). A more in-depth look: High Performance Computational Techniques for the Simplex Method/YT. Most important HW-aspect is having enough RAM!

@sascha TY for the inputs. In an IP, where exactly would parallelism be used? In branch and cut, it appears to me that running multiple separation routines in parallel is the only thing that is fundamentally parallelizable because of independence of each run? Beyond this, if one uses CPLEX or Gurobi as a black box, then, there is nothing much that the user can do. Is this correct? Also, regarding RAM, once we have a basic level of RAM, is not the bottleneck the speed of the processor?

RAM is more a binary-like factor: it either works or not. Then it's the "speed of your processor" but also your memory-subsystem (as in memory-channels) where consumer- and server-cpus differ. I don't have numbers here, but it's rather well-known that you will see slow-downs when running multiple (even n_core=1) solvers in parallel ("user-provided oracle-like parallelization") due to memory-bandwith bottlenecks. See this. But honestly: don't overestimate the HW-factor: In the end, your modelling and maybe solver-tuning is more important.

@One_Cable5781, also see this and this links.

While there is some work being done on LP/IP solvers using GPUs, to the best of my knowledge none of the major solvers (CPLEX, FICO Xpress, Gurobi, SAS) exploit GPUs, so I would consider that a non-issue.
Regarding RAM v. CPU cores, the major solvers can use parallel threading automatically, but there are diminishing returns to more threads. I don't know the details of all the solvers, but CPLEX will create separate copies of the problem matrix (or portions of it) for each parallel thread, so with a large model you might run out of RAM, limiting the usefulness of the parallel threads. With a small model, RAM is likely not an issue. That means the tradeoff depends on how large your problems tend to be and whether they benefit much from parallel threading, the latter being an empirical question.

Recently, NVIDIA is developing cuOpt and has now implemented PDLP, primal-dual linear programming, with GPU acceleration. They mentioned:

NVIDIA cuOpt has now implemented PDLP with GPU acceleration. Using
cutting-edge algorithms, NVIDIA hardware, dedicated CUDA features, and
NVIDIA GPU libraries, the cuOpt LP solver achieves over 5,000x faster
performance compared to CPU-based solvers.
This post examines the key components of LP solver algorithms, GPU
acceleration in LP, and cuOpt performance on Mittelmann’s benchmark
and Min Cost Flow problem instances.

For more details please, see this link:

Accelerate Large Linear Programming Problems with NVIDIA cuOpt


But the question was about integer programming.
